# How to compare value in Examples on Scenario Outline versus the Actual value on the Actual page using Cucumber/Selenium/Java

Tags: java, selenium, automation, cucumber

Given: Open the app

When: Enter username and password

Then: user is able to login

And verify the Actual Price

And Compare to the Expected price

Examples:

```
|Actual Price                           | Expected Price|

|"//div[@class='actual_price']//span[2]"|    USD 100.00| 

|"//div[@class='actual_price']//span[2]"|    USD 200.00|
```

Step def to get the Actual price is:

```
@And("^verify the \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void gettxt(String expectedPrice) throws Throwable {
    String actualprice= driver.findElement(By.xpath(actualprice)).getText();

    try{
    if(expectedPrice.equals(actualPrice)){
        System.out.println("Price is correct");
        System.out.println("Expected Price: " + expectedPrice);
        System.out.println("Actual Price: " + actualPrice);
    }else{
        System.out.println("Price is not correct");
        System.out.println("Expected Price: " + expectedPrice);
        System.out.println("Actual Price: " + actualPrice);
    }
}catch (Exception e){
    return;
    }
```

Question is how can I compare the actual and expected price. thanks for all your help.. the Actual price column in the example is the xpath to get the text on the UI for the actual value displayed, then the expected price column is the expected value.
Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: You should look at junit https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/assertions or even testng assertions. Even hamcrest matchers...

Comment: First you have to get the actual price value and compare it with expected value. and then apply your condition, when both price values are match.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer, yes I did get the actual price see my step definition, but I am not sure how can I compare it on the expected price on the example data table.

Comment: basically my question is how can I compare the actual column versus the expected price column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you have put in here seems to be incorrect.

The regular expression to match Gherkin in the step definition will take the xpath from the Examples. This xpath string will get stored in variable expectedprice as per the function you have defined.

By Your statement `String actualprice= driver.findElement(By.xpath(actualprice)).getText();`, i assume that, you are trying to get the value of actual price from the xpath and then trying to compare it with expectedPrice you have passed in the Examples section. if this is correct then you need to rewrite you code

Your feature file

```
Given: Open the app
When: Enter username and password
Then: user is able to login
And verify the Actual Price
And compare to the Expected Price

Examples:
|Actual Price                           | Expected Price|
|"//div[@class='actual_price']//span[2]"|    USD 100.00 | 
|"//div[@class='actual_price']//span[2]"|    USD 200.00 |
```

Your Step definition

```
String actualPrice = null;
@And("^verify the \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void gettxt(String actualPricePath) throws Throwable {
            actualPrice= driver.findElement(By.xpath(actualpricePath)).getText();
}

@And("^Compare to the \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void comparePrices(String expectedPrice){
    Assert.assertEquals(expectedPrice, actualPrice, "The actual price is not equal to expected price");
}
```

Comment: yes you are correct. I have updated the code and now it is working.. thanks.

Comment: The Solution looks Apt. I heard there is a way in BDD called Scenario Context to share the values between the steps. Try a luck when you have time.